# How do I read an image from RAM into a consistent format?

Tags: image, image-processing, rust

In C++ I am used to using stb_image to load image data to and from RAM.

I am writing a rust program where I have loaded some PNGs and JPEGs as raw binary data.

I am trying to use the image crate to read and decompress the ray byte data into the data and metadata (i.e. image dimensions and raw pixel byte data). I need to then re compress the data s a png and print it to disk, to make sure the data is ok (I will use the raw buffers later on).

To that effect I have this

```
let image_data = image::load_from_memory(bytes).unwrap();
```

where `bytes` is the raw image data.

Problem n1, this seems to create a 3 channel image for jpegs, I need a 4 channel image for both pngs and jpegs. So for jpegs I need the image crate to add padding. But if I try to cast it using `as_rgba8` I can no longer get the width and the height of the image.

Then I am trying to read the data into a custom struct, like this:

```rust
let mut raw_data = Vec::<u8>::new();

let width = image_data.width() as usize;
let height = image_data.height() as usize;

raw_data.extend_from_slice(image_data.as_bytes());
println!("{}", image_data.width());
println!("{}", image_data.height());
println!("{}", image_data.height() * image_data.width() * 3);
println!("{}", raw_data.len());

let texture = 
    Texture
    {
        width,
        height,
        channel_num : 4,
        format : ImageFormat::RGBA8,
        data : raw_data,
    };
```

This part seems to work, next I am trying to re-compress the data dn print to disk:

```rust
let tmp = RgbaImage::from_raw(
    texture.width as u32,
    texture.height as u32,
    texture.data.as_bytes().to_vec()).unwrap();

tmp.save("tmp.png");
```

In this case I am getting a `None` error on attempting the unwrap. I don't understand why since the byte buffer does have enough data to contain the full image, it was literally created by that image.

I am somewhat lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] this seems to create a 3 channel image for jpegs, I need a 4 channel image for both pngs and jpegs. [...] But if I try to cast it using as_rgba8 I can no longer get the width and the height of the image.

You want to *convert* the underlying image buffer, rather than cast the image. This is done with the `to_*` family of methods in [`DynamicImage`](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.3/image/enum.DynamicImage.html). This works regardless of whether the dynamic image was obtained from a file or from memory (both [`open`](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.3/image/fn.open.html) and [`load_from_memory`](https://docs.rs/image/0.24.3/image/fn.load_from_memory.html) return a `DynamicImage`).

```rust
use image::{RgbaImage, open}; // 0.24.3

let img = open("example.jpg")?;

println!(
    "Before: {}x{} {:?} ({} channels)",
    img.width(),
    img.height(),
    img.color(),
    img.color().channel_count()
);

let img: RgbaImage = img.to_rgba8();

println!(
    "After: {}x{} ({} channels)",
    img.width(),
    img.height(),
    img.sample_layout().channels
);
```

Note how the second `img` is already known at compile time to be an RGBA image. As an image buffer, you can freely retrieve any property or pixel data that you wish.

Possible output:

```
Before: 2864x2480 Rgb8 (3 channels)
After: 2864x2480 (4 channels)
```